# How to display locations beside map in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8. Please suggest me how to bind locations with a map. I have to get an output as in the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: This question really is too broad for the SSE format. A quick google search on what you are trying should return you this blog post: https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-location-finder-search-using-sxa.html -that should help you